# API specification for OpenStack

Tags: python, openstack, keystone

Is there a Web page (such as Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) where you can see the documentation of the classes that make up each component Openstack?

I'm looking for several days and can not find anything similar. The only documentation is located at:

- http://docs.openstack.org
- https://launchpad.net/keystone

But these docs don't have the specification of the classes tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openstack is opensource but is a pretty huge project with not just python code.

I would recommend that you download the source code and explore it yourself. 
Once you have defined the modules you are curious about, you can even generate your own
documentation using known tools.

The easiest I know is:

[epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/)

It will generate for you a class tree in a html or pdf format.